# remove first span element after input

Tags: jquery

How to remove first span element after `<input id="mytxt" type="textbox"/>` , if it exists?

```
 $('#mytxt').live('change', function(){
        //TO DO    
 }
```

Comment: Do you have to delete the next element of the <input> iff it is <span> ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Within your live function, do this:

```
$(this).next("span").remove();
```

Comment: only after 6 minutes @agentmilindu

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check the first "SPAN" element after the  element. so you have to go till the end of the document

```
var element = $(this).next();
while($(element)[0].tagName!="SPAN" && $(element).length!=0){
    element = $(element).next();
}
if($(element)[0].tagName=="SPAN"){
    $(element).remove();
}
```